problem with nextjs.org initial course, Unhandled Runtime Error
I'm learning nextjs by their website guide, but I'm on a problem that I cannot really find anywhere. Everything was good until this point:
https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/navigating-between-pages#pattern-showing-active-links - my localhost:3000/dashboard works charming, unless i add "use client"; directive on the top of my code. As soon as I do it this screen is thrown at me. Doing rest of the course doesnt work, all I can see is this error. Do you have any idea if it's something wrong with guide (which I doubt) or I am just dumb and can't see something? There's my nav-links.tsx code just in case:
It works as charm unless I add 'use client';
'use client';

import {
  UserGroupIcon,
  HomeIcon,
  DocumentDuplicateIcon,
} from '@heroicons/react/24/outline';
import Link from 'next/link'

// Map of links to display in the side navigation.
// Depending on the size of the application, this would be stored in a database.
const links = [
  { name: 'Home', href: '/dashboard', icon: HomeIcon },
  {
    name: 'Invoices',
    href: '/dashboard/invoices',
    icon: DocumentDuplicateIcon,
  },
  { name: 'Customers', href: '/dashboard/customers', icon: UserGroupIcon },
];

export default function NavLinks() {
  return (
    <>
      {links.map((link) => {
        const LinkIcon = link.icon;
        return (
          <Link
            key={link.name}
            href={link.href}
            className="flex h-[48px] grow items-center justify-center gap-2 rounded-md bg-gray-50 p-3 text-sm font-medium hover:bg-sky-100 hover:text-blue-600 md:flex-none md:justify-start md:p-2 md:px-3"
          >
            <LinkIcon className="w-6" />
            <p className="hidden md:block">{link.name}</p>
          </Link>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}

For context - I'm following the guide since project installation, so I doubt I could've messed something up. Would be nice if someone knows whats up.
Searched through reddit, stack overflow but couldn't find anything.

related

Yeah, it helps, but I'm still curious why is that, like shouldn't they mention this on the guide? Unless its a bug that's alive for a little bit too long. Thanks for solving that, but I'm still interested in how and why does this happen.
